# Pull Down on Comparator Input

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to use a comparator to detect an open circuited signal.

If I place a pull down resistor on the input as shown below, will the comparator operate correctly when Vin is removed and the inverting terminal is left open?

I am concerned that offset/bias voltage/current requirements will not be met if I use such a high value pull down resistor.

Edit: to be more clear, the reason I am asking this is because I used an extremely high impedance source (1M) as an input to to the comparator and the comparator did not function as expected. I suspect this was due to there not being sufficient bias current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBKDZo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Before your concern can be addressed, you need to consider "offset/bias voltage/current requirements". What requirements? You do realize that this varies between comparators, yes? So, until you specify exactly which comparator you plan to use, there is simply no way deal with your question.

Comment: I'll be using the LM139: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2901.pdf

Comment: What is -100nA max * 1M?

Comment: 1mV, however I am not sure how this affects the circuit because the current flows into the terminal

Comment: Check your calculator. Again. 100nA x 1Mohm?

Comment: And why do you think current will flow into the terminal? See the equivalent schematic on the data sheet and think about it.

Comment: On which page? I cant seem to find it

Comment: It's called Functional Block Diagram.

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values of the Vin signal that you want to detect as valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LM139 is a ruggedised version of LM339 a very common comparator.

This part has a PNP input stage, and an open circuited pin will float high in the absence of a pull down.

The data sheet says the bias current is up-to 100nA (at room temperature), so with a 1M pull down there could be 0.1V on the input pin. (at worst case allowed operating temperature it could be 300nA, and 0.3V)

The other input will have about 0.16V and given that the offset voltage (imprecision) is only 0.002V it should work (at room temp).

Comment: Thank you! I was reading this: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-038.pdf and the bias current was described as entering the input, which is why I was a little confused.

Comment: the MT038 tutorial uses an NPN input stage, which has the opposite polarity to the PNP stage in the LM139